# Hi, I want to use a google map like the reference in php how can I get this map

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-apps

I am sending a reference link I want a google map like this one , can any body help me in

this regard. http://www.reclamefolder.nl/kaart

the above site there is a map which multiple pointer and logo of companies on the marker

pointer how I use this one in PHP .

Thanks.![enter image description here][1]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [**GoogleMap3**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) this provide you with guideline about how you can play with Google Map.

You can also use Google Map3 using [**jQueryGoogleMap3**](http://gmap3.net).

Comment: Yes I have download the Gmap 3 . It is very difficult to make it. I mean is there any PHP class that can can easily manageable . it is okay for static map but how can we make it dynamic. Is there any class.